# CSS3 Animation not working on Firefox But working on chrome

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my animation work on firefox, Its working fine on google chrome but not in firefox or any other browser.

Here is the html markup

```
<div id="blo"></div>
```

and CSS sheet

```
#blo {
width: 44px;
height: 43px;
background: url(http://www.noirextreme.com/digital/Earth-Color4096.jpg);border-radius: 50%;
background-size: 86px, 43px;
box-shadow: inset 5px 0 17px 0px rgb(5, 5, 5), inset -2px 1px 3px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
-webkit-animation-name: rotate;
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation-name: rotate;
-moz-animation-duration: 4s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
-ms-animation-name: rotate;
-ms-animation-duration: 4s;
-ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-name: rotate;
animation-duration: 4s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
z-index: 9999;
position: relative;


@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from { background-position-x: 0px; }
    to { background-position-x: 86px; }
}


@-ms-keyframes rotate {
    from { background-position-x: 0px; }
    to { background-position-x: 86px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    from { background-position-x: 0px; }
    to { background-position-x: 86px; }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J22TN/1/

```
@keyframes rotate {
    from { background-position-x: 0px; }
    to { background-position-x: 86px; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change @keyframes to this:

```
@keyframes rotate {
        from { background-position: 0 0; }  // changed position-x to position: 0 0
        to { background-position: 86px 0; }
    }
```

And also, remove all the `-moz-` lines. `@keyframe animations` are directly supported by `firefox`!

**Your Final CSS should be this:**

```
#blo {
    width: 44px;
    height: 43px;
    background: url(http://www.noirextreme.com/digital/Earth-Color4096.jpg);border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: 86px, 43px;
    box-shadow: inset 5px 0 17px 0px rgb(5, 5, 5), inset -2px 1px 3px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;

    }

    @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
        from { background-position-x: 0px; }
        to { background-position-x: 86px; }
    }

    @keyframes rotate {
        from { background-position: 0 0; }
        to { background-position: 86px 0; }
    }
```

Comment: -ms- needs to go as well

Comment: Good Answer But Still its not working on IE and other browers

Comment: `IE 10` and `opera 12` versions support `CSS 3 animations`. **Their earlier versions will NOT!** and this one is working fine in `Firefox` for me.