# CSS animation works in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: html, css

CSS animation works perfect in chrome,edge and safari but not in firefox.Here is my code

```
  @-webkit-keyframes roll1 {
    0% { transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    10% { -moz-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    20% { -moz-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
    30% { -moz-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    40% { -moz-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    50% { -moz-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    60% { -moz-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    70% { -moz-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
    80% { -moz-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    90% { -moz-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -moz-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}

   #roll1:hover,
    #roll1:focus {
    -moz-animation-name: roll1;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
   }
```

and my HTML code.

```
<div id="roll">
            <button type="button" name="next" id="roll1" class="btn btn-primary rollbutton" onclick="displayQuestion();">Roll Dice</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the -moz- lines. @keyframe animations are directly supported by firefox!

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145128/css3-animation-not-working-on-firefox-but-working-on-chrome) link.

Answer (score 0):

`@-webkit-keyframes` is specially for chrome, you should use simply `@keyframes`

also you don't need `-moz` prefix mozilla do support raw `transform` property

```css
@keyframes roll1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
}
#roll1:hover,
#roll1:focus {
  -moz-animation-name: roll1;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="roll">
  <button type="button" name="next" id="roll1" class="btn btn-primary rollbutton" onclick="displayQuestion();">Roll Dice</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @misterManSam is right, `-moz-` prefix isn't needed anymore. Prefixless `transform` syntax is all that all modern browsers need.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you used -moz- that supports only for firefox browser you I have added -webkit- that is used for chrom, same like you can use -o- -ms- for all browser support.

```css
 @-webkit-keyframes roll1 {
    0% { transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); 
    
    }
    10% {
      -moz-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); 
      -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); 
      transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); 
    
    }
    20% {
      -moz-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
      -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
      transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
    }
    30% {
      -moz-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
      -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
      transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    40% {
      -moz-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
      -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
      transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
    
    }
    50% {
      -moz-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
      -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
      transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
    }
    60% { -moz-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
      -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
      transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
    }
   70% { -moz-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); 
  -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); 
  transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);
 }
 80% { 
  -moz-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); 
  -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); 
  transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); 
 }
    90% {
  -moz-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
 }
    100% { 
  -moz-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); 
  -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); 
  transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); 
 }
}

   #roll1:hover,
    #roll1:focus {
    -moz-animation-name: roll1;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
      
    -webkit-animation-name: roll1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
      
    animation-name: roll1;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
    transform-origin:50% 50%;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
   }
```

```html
    <div id="roll">
                <button type="button" name="next" id="roll1" class="btn btn-primary rollbutton" onclick="displayQuestion();">Roll Dice</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the point of `-moz-transform` property inside the `@-webkit-keyframes` block? What browser is it supposed to be supported in?